# Angularjs - ngSwitch $broadcast

Tags: angularjs, controller, nested, broadcast, ng-switch

In my app i have an ng-switch and inside one of tab i have a div with a second controller like this:

```
<div ng-controller="first">
  <div ng-switch on="tab">
    <div ng-switch-default></div>
    <div ng-switch-when="2">
      <div ng-controller="second">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm communicating with second controller using $scope.$broadcast but it's inside ng-switch and seems not working because of it. First question why?

When I put second controller out of ngswitch chain it works. BUT when I change $scope.tab value nothing happens. It should be catched by ng-switch again. Second question why?
Someone can help me ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First: `ng-swith` directive is working like a switch case in javascript. When `$scope.tab = 1`, "seconed" controller wont render in the DOM. So there is no controller to communicate with...

Second: if you put the "second" controller outside the switch case, `$scope.tab` has no effect on it.

Try to explain in words what you are trying to do. There is no logic in your code